# Weird result of Java Integer left shift

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm a little confused now by java left shift operation,

```
1<<31 =  0x80000000  --> this I can understand
```

But

```
1<<32 =  1       Why is this?
1<<33 =  2
```

Looks like more shifting values, modulus 32 of the value is taken.

Thanks everybody for the replying and giving the quote from JLS.

I just want to know more. Any idea of the reason why it's designed in this way? Or is it just some convention? Apparently C doesn't have this quirk?

> > Thanks to @paxdiablo. Looks like C declares this behaviour undefined.

I have some personal assumption here:

> ARM architecture Reference Manual A7.1.38
>
> Syntax
>   LSL Rd, Rm, #immed_5
>
> where:
>
> **Rd**  Is the register that stores the result of the operation.
>
> **Rm** Is the register containing the value to be shifted.
>
> **immed_5** Specifies the shift amount, in the range 0 to 31.

On instruction level, the immeidate **immed_5** takes only 5 bits to avoid meaningless operations so as to save some instruction space. I guess high level languages just unitize this convention to avoid meaningless effort when compile to instructions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the Java Language Specification `15.19. Shift Operators` (slightly paraphrased):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, ***only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used*** as the shift distance.  It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator `&` with the mask value `0x1f` ,or `0b11111`. The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `31`, inclusive.

That means that (for example) `33`, being the 6-bit binary `100001`, is reduced to the 5-bit `00001` before being used. So `x << 33` is identical to `x << 1`.

Comment: Thanks @Paxdiablo. Do you have any idea of the reason why it's designed in this way? Or is it just some convention? Apparently C doesn't have this quirk?

Comment: @Bill, C has a much ***worse*** quirk, to wit `If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.` Java fully specified quite a few behaviours that C didn't, a sort of a clean-up made from experience. In terms of why it won't shift 32 bits and just set the value to zero, it's hard to see a use case for that. Bit shifting tends to be used for extracting/setting bits, and you can't extract any useful bits from a value you have shifted into oblivion :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1 << 32));
```

Shifts binary 1(10) by 32 times to the left. Hence: 1 in decimal

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1 << 33));
```

Now, int is of 4 bytes,hence 32 bits. So when you do shift by 33, it's equivalent to shift by 1. Hence : 2 in decimal

Comment: If a 32-bit binary 1 was _actually_ shifted 32-bits left, the result would be *zero,* not one. Maybe you're thinking of rotation?