# Java bitwise operator <<

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Can someone explain why the following bitwise expressions return different results:

```
System.out.println((-1<<31)<<1);   // it prints 0
System.out.println(-1<<32);        // it prints -1
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/34193787/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3170412/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki: Yes, it is similar.

Answer (score 14):

`-1<<32` is equivalent to `-1<<0`, i.e. a no-op. The reason is that the shift distance `(32)` is AND-ed with `0x1f` and `32 & 0x1f` is 0.

This is defined in the [JLS #15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) (emphasis mine):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then ***only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance***. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

The shift count value is used modulo 32. So the second example is actually the same as shifting by 0.