# Is the lost information by left shifting stored somewhere in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

So I was experimenting with left shifting in Java and I found something I didn't understand. The code below describes it.

```
int x = -1 << 31;
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(-1) + " -1\n");
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(x) + " " + x + "\n");

// output
11111111111111111111111111111111 -1
10000000000000000000000000000000 -2147483648
```

So I just got rid of 31 1s on the left of the integer -1, and the result was what I expected. However, after I tried to left shift 1 more position, instead of getting 0, I got -1.

```
int x = -1 << 32; // one more left shift
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(-1) + " -1\n");
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(x) + " " + x + "\n");

// output
11111111111111111111111111111111 -1
11111111111111111111111111111111 -1
```

Then I tried left shifting the minimum integer value, -2147483648, directly by 1. And I got the expected value 0.

```
System.out.println(-2147483648 << 1); // the output is 0
```

Can someone explain to me what happened behind the scenes?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34193834/2891664. `x << 32` is the same as `x << 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [JLS 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

So `-1 << 32` is the same as `-1 << 0`, explaining your result.